# Merge multiple CSV files into one single file and have their file names added as the last field with field name as 'File Name'

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, merge

I would like to merge multiple CSV files, (all files are in the same format), available in a directory, and their file name should be added as the last field.

Since the field names are same for all the CSV files, the field names should not repeat. I would like to achieve this using batch scripting.

File1 example:

```
C1  C2
--  --  
AR1 BR1 
AR2 BR2
```

File2 example:

```
C1  C2
--  --
CR1 DR1 
CR2 DR2
```

Merge File should be:

```
C1  C2  File Name
--- --- ---------
AR1 BR1 File1
AR2 BR2 File1
CR1 DR1 File2
CR2 DR2 File2
```

I tried below code, it merges the files perfectly, without repeating the header. All I need to add is the file name of each file and add it as the last field in the merge file.

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
pushd C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\Test\New folder
SET first=y
SET newfile=Merge_CSV_HB_R5217476_REDReport.csv
for %%F in (*.csv) do IF NOT %%F==%newfile% (
    if defined first (
        COPY /y "%%F" %newfile% >nul
        set "first="
    ) else (
        FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (%%F) DO >> %newfile% ECHO %%i
    )
)
```

Comment: We need your `File1` and `File2` content not a similar represetation of how it may look when displayed in a GUI application. Please [Edit] your question to replace those examples.

Comment: I have never seen a CSV file using a normal space as separator. Common separators are `,` (comma), `;` (semicolon in German countries and important to know as being the default end of line character in a `for /F` loop; a line could start therefore with `;` resulting in skipping that line by default by `for /F` resulting in missing lines in final CSV file), `|` or horizontal tab character (TSV file).

Comment: ulin, I have removed your recent [Edit]. That is an image showing once again, a graphical representation of how a particular piece of software displays your CSV. It is of no use to us in determining how to add information to the underlying file. Please open your csv files in a plain text editor, (such as notepad), or even a Command Prompt window, (`type "filename.csv"`). Then copy and paste the content directly into a code box within your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directory and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

pushd "%sourcedir%"
SET "fffl=y"
SET "newfile=Merge_CSV_HB_R5217476_REDReport.csv"

(
for %%e in (*.csv) do IF NOT "%%e"=="%newfile%" (
 SET "first=y"
 FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%y IN ("%%e") DO (
  IF DEFINED fffl (
   ECHO %%y File Name
  ) ELSE (
    if NOT defined first ECHO %%y %%~ne
  )
 SET "fffl="
 SET "first="
 )
)
)>"%newfile%"

TYPE "%newfile%"

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

The original code works by using the `first` flag to detect the first of the `.csv` files, copy that directly, and then append the remaining files, all bar the first line.

The question requires that *every* line of every file be processed, so the `skip` method is not available.

Hence, we need to detect the first line of the first file (`fffl`) since that line requires special processing - adding the extra column name and the non-first line of every file (not `first`, where `first` is re-initialised when a new file is selected for processing) to add the filename.

So - assuming that the underline line does not appear in the source data, we can simply use `fffl` and `first` as Booleans to select the data that needs to be regurgitated and supplemented.

Note the use of quotes throughout to allow for the possibility that the file/directorynames contain separators like spaces, and the use of the modifier `~n` to select the name part only of the file being processed and on the general principle that the quoted-set method is more robust.

Also, I've changed the metavariable-names so that they are not also metavariable-modifiers.

Note that the entire `for` statement is enclosed by `(`...`)>"filename"`. This creates a new file with the accumulation of the data `echo`ed, reducing the number of file-open-closes generated by the *append* approach.

And, of course, I've closed the `pushd/popd` bracket having `type`d the generated file.

Comment: Thank you so much @Magoo, your code achieved most of my requirement, but only one thing, the file name is being added as a value to the existing last column. The file name should be a separate column. For example, If my two files have 10 columns each, the file name should be the 11th column in the merge file. Thank you once again.

Comment: According to the example data you have posted, your column-separator character is space. Plese post representative data. Change `…ECHO %%y …` to  `…ECHO %%y,…` to use commas as column-separators, for example. You may also need to change `File Name` / `%%~ne` to  `"File Name"` / `"%%~ne"` if your format us in fact quote-delimited ?-separated.